# how can i find my registred users is in online or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-config

we have a learning system web Application that developed with ASP.Net and we decide to add new feature to it .

we need to find users who are online in a `OnlineClass` .
At first i think we can set `user Status` in `UserTable` with making `true` status Field in `login` and make it `false` when `Session_End` raised in the `global.asax` (it raised when `timeout = 1` minute in `Web Config` had been finished.).

In other word after 1 minutes user status change to false.
In Web Config I set :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

in `Global.asax` :

```
 protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AccountDefine accountDefine = (AccountDefine)Session["AccountDefine"];
        AccountBL accountBL = new AccountBL();

        if (UserID != null)
        {
            if (accountDefine.AccountID != 0)
            {
                accountBL.SetUserStatusTo(UserID, false);
            }
        }

    }
```

it works but we find bigger problem !
In a class when user must study and watch an online flash lesson user have to stay a long time in page and read and watch !

We can't use session because user need a long time to read a book we can `set session to 1 minutes` for change status .

Now, What can i do for this problem ? Is other better way to find user status ?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a property to your user:

```
public DateTime LatestActivity { get; set; }
```

and whenever the user does something, be that log in, request a resource, etc, set:

```
user.LatestActivity = DateTime.Now;
```

Then you can get a list of recently active users by calling something similar to

```
var loggedInUsers = allUsers.Where(
    user => user.LatestActivity > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15));
```

If your users are going to be idle for a long time, what you could do is use a JavaScript timer to poll a "keep active" server side method which simply updates the `LatestActivity` property.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "LastPolled" datetime column to your database table. Create a javascript function to do an AJAX call every minute, using window.SetInterval().  The server side call can then update the status to True, and update the "LastPolled" column.  On database server side, schedule a SQL Server Agent Task to update all entries to Status = false, when "LastPolled" value is > 1 minute from present.